# 3 functions in your code that have been deprecated in the current version of PHP 7

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using PHP 7 and am trying to find a solution on how my code should be because of 3 functions I am using that have been depricated in current version of php 7.

The three functions are:

> ```
> mysql_close()
> mysql_query()
> mysql_select_db()
> ```

Here is my code:

```
 <?php  
 //mysql database connectivity  
 //inserting form data into the database  
 if(@$valid==true)  
{  
 $con= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root"); 
 mysql_select_db("usersignup", $con);  
 @$a=$_POST['fname'];  
 @$b=$_POST['lname'];  
 @$c=$_POST['email'];  
 @$d=$_POST['cell'];  
 @$e=$_POST['add'];  
 @$f=$_POST['age'];  
 @$g=$_POST['gen'];  
 @$i=$_POST['username'];  
 @$j=$_POST['pass'];  
 @$h=$_POST['mtype'];  
 mysql_query("insert into user (FirstName,LastName,Email,CPhone,Address,Age,Gender,Username,Password,MType) values('$a','$b','$c','$d','$e','$f','$g','$i','$j','$h')");  
 header("Location:form1.php");  
 mysql_close($con);  
}
```

?>

I have looked at some solutions offered that suggest the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used, The problem is I havent found a practical way to impliment that.

Comment: I dont understand your answer kindly explain it a little

Comment: don't mix `mysql_*` with `mysqli_*` or `PDO` . Also a very bad coding practice. skipping errors through @ will make you in a lot of trouble sometime.

Comment: I have added code in yur question cut and paste and check . remove from here.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `mysqli` with `prepared statements`, its more secure.

```
 $a=$_POST['fname'];  
 $b=$_POST['lname'];  
 $c=$_POST['email'];  
 $d=$_POST['cell'];  
 $e=$_POST['add'];  
 $f=$_POST['age'];  
 $g=$_POST['gen'];  
 $i=$_POST['username'];  
 $j=$_POST['pass'];  
 $h=$_POST['mtype']; 

$query= $mysqli->prepare("insert into user (FirstName,LastName,Email,CPhone,Address,Age,Gender,Username,Password,MType) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

$query->bind_param('ssssssssss',$a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f,$g,$i,$j,$h);

if (!$query->execute())
{
    $flag = false;
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard thanks for the suggestions, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

PHP7 no longer supports mysql_* functions. You need to chose either PDO or mysqli APIs instead. You can use the following mysqli functions to replace the deprecated functions.

[mysqli_select_db](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php)

[mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

mysqli_close

Eg:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "test");
mysqli_select_db($link, "world");
// SQL Logic goes here
mysqli_close($link);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the deprecated function with the newest one.

```
mysql_close()      => mysqli_close()
mysql_query()      => mysqli_query()
mysql_select_db()  => mysqli_select_db()
```

so your code will be:

```
<?php  
//mysql database connectivity  
//inserting form data into the database  
if(@$valid==true){  
   $con= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root"); 
   mysqli_select_db("usersignup", $con);  
   @$a=$_POST['fname'];  
   @$b=$_POST['lname'];  
   @$c=$_POST['email'];  
   @$d=$_POST['cell'];  
   @$e=$_POST['add'];  
   @$f=$_POST['age'];  
   @$g=$_POST['gen'];  
   @$i=$_POST['username'];  
   @$j=$_POST['pass'];  
   @$h=$_POST['mtype'];  
   mysqli_query("insert into user (FirstName,LastName,Email,CPhone,Address,Age,Gender,Username,Password,MType) values('$a','$b','$c','$d','$e','$f','$g','$i','$j','$h')");  
   header("Location:form1.php");  
   mysqli_close($con);  
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

The same but with `mysqli_` with only one difference that you have to pass db name in `mysqli_connect( ... db name` as last param

```
// mysqli connect
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root", "usersignup"); 

// mysqli query
mysqli_query("
  insert into user 
  (FirstName,LastName,Email,CPhone,Address,Age,Gender,Username,Password,MType)
  values('$a','$b','$c','$d','$e','$f','$g','$i','$j','$h')
");  

// connection close
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: what you mean @Anant ?

Comment: We are here not solving logickal issue of the code (like validation or mysql injection) @Anant , we are solving issue with mysql and mysqli usage issue

Comment: There is validation its just that I didnt post all the code here.

Comment: Actually John and Anant mentioning good point to improve your code to use %s %i in `mysqli_query(` or `bind_param` in pdo you can read more about it here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp OR http://markonphp.com/mysqli-select-prepared-statements/

Comment: atleast you can point those issues, and if you are doing same thing then what's the purpose to give the code.

Comment: @Anant i'm answering on exact question which is asked, i'm not going so deep if you want to point `Good` then post your own answer

Comment: I have done that alreaDY

Comment: With posting answer in question directly with text `Please try this` :D, instead writing normal answer ...